# I am using redux in react native application to fetch and display data but its not updating on data change from backend

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I am using Redux in my React-Native application.
I am fetching the data from api call and on success rendoring it on ListItem.
I am able to fetch and display data but data is not auto updating unless and until I revisit the page.
Even values are not storing into the app
I am calling method from actions in constructor and componentDidMount method.
Can you Please check the code and tell me where am I going wrong.

Here is action.js

```
import { 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_REQUEST, 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_FAILURE 
} from './types';

export const fetchingProductRequest = () => ({
    type : FETCHING_PRODUCT_REQUEST
});

export const fetchingProductSuccess = (json) => ({
    type : FETCHING_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
    payload : json
});

export const fetchingProductFailure = (error) => ({
    type : FETCHING_PRODUCT_FAILURE,
    payload : error
});

export const fetchProduct = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchingProductRequest());
        try {
            let response = await fetch("http://phplaravel-325095-1114213.cloudwaysapps.com/api/shop/shop");
            let json = await response.json();
            dispatch(fetchingProductSuccess(json));
        } catch(error) {
            dispatch(fetchingProductFailure(error));
        }
    }
}
```

My reducer.js

```
import { 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_REQUEST, 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, 
    FETCHING_PRODUCT_FAILURE 
} from './../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    loading : false,
    errorMessage : '',
    shops: []
}

const products = ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCHING_PRODUCT_REQUEST :
            return { ...state, loading: true} ;
        case FETCHING_PRODUCT_SUCCESS : 
            return { ...this.state, loading: false, shops: action.payload };
        case FETCHING_PRODUCT_FAILURE : 
            return { ...state, loading: false, errorMessage: action.payload};
    }
};

export default products;
```

product.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { FlatList , ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

import { fetchProduct } from './../../actions/products';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import propTypes from 'prop-types';

class Product extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchProduct();
    this.state = {
      loading : true,
      shops : '',
     isFetching: false,
     active : true,
    }
   }


   fetchProducts() {
    const shopid = 13;
    fetch(`http://phplaravel-325095-1114213.cloudwaysapps.com/api/shop/shop`)
        .then(response => response.json())
          .then((responseJson)=> {
              this.setState({
                 loading: false,
                 shops: responseJson
              })
             alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.shops));
        })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
   }

    componentDidMount(){
      // this.fetchProducts();
      this.props.fetchProduct().then(this.setState({loading : false}));
    }



  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <ListItem
    title={item.name}
    subtitle={item.name}
    leftAvatar={{
      source: item.avatar && { uri: item.avatar },
      title: item.name[0]
    }}
    bottomDivider
    chevron
  />
)

render () {
    if(!this.state.loading)
    { 
      if(this.props.shopsInfo.loading)
      {
        return (
        <ActivityIndicator/>
        )
      }
      else
      {
        return (
        <FlatList
                vertical
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={this.props.shopsInfo.shops}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
              />
      )
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator/>
        )
    }
  }
}

Product.propTypes = {
  fetchProduct:  propTypes.func.isRequired
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { shopsInfo: state };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchProduct: () => dispatch(fetchProduct())
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Product);
```

Comment: Updating data from backend wont reflect in app , You need to check periodically to achieve that , You can make some customised approach to get a better user experience by referring life cycle of react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Not updating on data change from backend.**

You have to call an api on regular interval to get updated data. Redux implementation doesn't mean it will fetch data from server whenever there is any change.

**2. Even values are not storing into the app**

If you are expecting redux will store data even if you will close/kill an application than it will not. You have persist data in-order to use it or store it in cache. Take a look at [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: Ohh ok, I got it. For me updating on data change is important.. Can you provide me any quick guide for it.

Comment: Well there is no direct way to implement it in my knowledge. What you can do is just check data change on regular interval or may be socket programming which can notify you whenever there is data change. I will not suggest socket if it is not large product.

Comment: Ok.. I'll use regular interval to update state in actions. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your passing wrong props in mapStateToProps function.
In reducer your updating the response value in shop props.
In order to get the updated value you need to pass shops property to get the value.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
   const { shops: state };  
   return {shops};
}
```

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { shopsInfo: state };
}    Here shopsInfo is just like a variable to store all the states from props.

Comment: If your passing the full state, then check the  `mapStateToProps` and the component using console, whether your updated data is returning here. If you don't receive the data, just check your configure store, whether its properly updated the reducer.